# Morphic Breaking down borders

Tags: pharo, morphic

How can i break Morph borders into something like this??

[image]

I want to use these Morphs for Maze

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps instead of breaking the borders, you might want to add submorphs on the edges (For example, LineMorphs) using a ProportionalLayout.

The Pharo Collaboractive book is an excellent extra source to start learning about Pharo Smalltalk. Perhaps the Layout section might be helpful: http://book.pharo-project.org/book/LanguageAndLibraries/GUI/PolymorphTutorial/Layout/

Another interesting source can be the examples on laying out submorphs in the Squeak Wiki: http://wiki.squeak.org/squeak/589

Answer (score 1):

Instances of PolygonMorph class can be used to make these shapes (see examples in browser)